# If $f=u+iv$ is differentiable in a domain $D$ with either $u(x,y), v(x,y),$ or arg$f(z)$ constant in $D$, then $f(z)$ is constant in $D$.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

**Theorem:** If $f=u+iv$ is differentiable in a domain $D$ with either $u(x,y), v(x,y),$ or arg$f(z)$ constant in $D$, then $f(z)$ is constant in $D$. Moreover, if$f$ and $g$ are two differentiable functions in a domain $D$, and Im$f(z)$=Im$g(z)$ on $D$, then $f(z)=g(z)$+real constant.

To prove the first part, suppose that $u(x,y)=c$ on $D$. Then $u_x=u_y=0$ on $D$, and by the Cauchy-Riemann equations, $v_y=v_x=0$. Therefore $v$ is constant on $D$. The same can be said of when $u(x,y)$ is constant in $D$.

However, I don't know how to prove this when arg$f(z)$ is constant in $D$. How can I use the Cauchy-Riemann equations in this case?

Also, for the second part, I can use the first part with Im$f(z)-g(z)=0$ on $D$, to easily conclude that $f(z)=g(z)$+constant, but I don't understand how I can show that the constant must be real.

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone explains the solution to the above questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\operatorname{arg}f(z)$ is constant. If $v = 0$, then $f$ is real-valued analtyic function, which implies $f$ is constant. If $v \neq 0$, then $u = \lambda v$ for some real constant $\lambda$. So $0 = u - \lambda v = \operatorname{Re}((1 + i\lambda)f)$. So $(1 + i\lambda)f$ is a purely imaginary analytic function, which implies $(1 + i\lambda)f$ is constant. Since $1 + i\lambda$ is a nonzero constant, then $f$ is constant. As for the second part, if $\operatorname{Im}f(z) = \operatorname{Im}g(z)$, then $f - g$ is an analytic function that only takes real values, which implies $f - g$ is constant. If $z_0 \in D$, then the constant is equal to $f(z_0) - g(z_0)$, a real number. Therefore, $f$ differs from $g$ by a real constant.

Comment: Could you explain why $|f(z)|$ is constant if argf(z) is constant?

Comment: @user135204 I've made the changes. Please take another look.

Comment: Thanks, but I've got a few questions. First why is $u=\lambda v$ if $v\neq 0$. Next, why is $u-\lambda v=\operatorname{Re}((1+i\lambda)f)$? Also, how can we guarantee that $1+i\lambda$ is a nonzero constant? Why can't $\lambda$ be $i$?

Comment: @user135204 if $\operatorname{arg}f(z)$ is constant, with constant value $\theta$, say, and $v \neq 0$, then $u = v\cot \theta$. Note from this that $\lambda$ is a real constant, so $1 + i\lambda$ is nonzero. Finally, to get $u - \lambda$ as the real part of $(1 + i \lambda)f$, write out $f = u + iv$, and calculate $(1 + i\lambda)(u + iv) = (u - \lambda v) + i(v + \lambda u)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\arg f(z)=\theta_0$, and then
$$f(z)=|f(z)|e^{\rm{i}\theta_0},\qquad \forall z\in D.$$
Let
$$F(z)=e^{-\rm{i}\theta_0}f(z)=|f(z)|\in \mathbb R,\qquad \forall z\in D,$$
then $F$ is real-valued holomorphic function,
which implies $f$ is constant.