Proof that the function $f(z)$ is constant in a domain $D$
I want to prove that if $f$ is analytic on a domain $D$ and $\text{Re}(f)= \alpha$, $\text{Im}(f)= \alpha$ or $\text{Arg}(z)= \alpha$, then $f$ is constant on $D$.
I was thinking that one way to show this is to verify, that for those given conditions, $f'(z)=0$ in $D$ and under it we have naturally that $f$ is constant. Let's take a look at the cases that may arise
If $\text{Re}(f)= \alpha$, for $f(z)=u(x, y)+ i v(x, y)=\alpha+iv(x, y)$ since $f$ is analytic in $D$, it satisfies the Cauchy- Riemann equations in $D$, so that
$$u_{x}=0=v_{y} \quad \quad u_{y}=0=-v_{x} $$
And $f'(z)=f_{x}(z)=u_{x}+iv_{x}=0+0i$, as $f'(z)=0$ then $f$ is constant for all $z \in D$
I think it goes without saying that they satisfy the C-R equations, this is analogous to the case when $\text{Im}(f)= \alpha$.
Now, when the argument of $z$ is $\alpha$, I guess I should use polar coordinates and the fact that:
$$f'(z)=e^{-i\text{arg}(z)}(u_{r}+iv_{r})$$
and I would arrive at the value of the derivative is null, is this feasible to prove the above?
Any help is welcome!

Do you mean $\operatorname{Arg}(z) = \alpha$ or $\operatorname{Arg}(f(z)) = \alpha$? The former doesn't really make sense as it makes no mention of $f$.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1535260/if-fz-analytic-in-the-domain-d-and-fz-0-so-fz-constant?rq=1

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1182838/if-f-uiv-is-differentiable-in-a-domain-d-with-either-ux-y-vx-y-or-a?rq=1
